# Algorithm for personality matching quiz where each answer can provide signal for different output types

Tags: algorithm, ranking

For those who are not familiar with personality quizzes, the idea behind them is you answer a few multiple choice questions and at the end you get a result for a predefined set that your answers most closely align to.

Normally these quizzes are designed such that each multiple choice answer option maps exclusively to one value in the output set. For example if the output set is [A,B,C], then answer 1 would only map to A, answer 2 would only map to B, etc.

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm where each multiple choice answer can provide signal to multiple values in the output set. For example if the output set is [A,B,C], then answer 1 would give 3 points to output A and 6 points to output C, answer 2 would give 5 points to output B and 2 points to output A and C etc.

My naive approach for this has been to just pick the output that has the most number of points, but this falls apart a bit if the total number of possible points in the quiz for option A is significantly more than the possible points for option C (there will end up being a heavy bias towards outputting A).

Is there a way I can rank the output options here given the input scores from the answers, and give every option a fair chance?

Comment: This is a very subjective question, as this algorithm doesn't really have any correct answer and will require tuning to "feel" right. That said, my first instinct is to choose the correct answer based on `points/total_possible_points` (where `total_possible_points` are the points received if every question had the answer that gave that output the most points`), meaning the output is chosen based more on how close to "optimal" the answers were for that output.

Comment: @dominicm00 I gave that `points/total_possible_points` method a bit of thought as well, I'm thinking of a scenario where someone gets 19/20 possible points for option A and 1/1 possible points for option C, it will skew towards option C heavily even though there isn't much signal there.

Comment: You should look at "naive bayes classifiers".

Comment: @user8811409 frankly, something like that scenario probably means you should better distribute the points in the quiz, since I'm assuming that you control the point values. That said, if you want to account for that scenario, I would use some sort of confidence method (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8idr1WZ1A7Q) based on the number of questions that contributed to the result to determine if there's enough data to reliably determine the answer.